# How to aggregate data based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[image]

i have table as shown above where there are two columns(Gender and year). i want to convert this into following format as shown below. any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': ['m', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f'],
                   'year': [2011, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2012]})
pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['Gender'])

Gender  f   m
year        
2011    0   3
2012    1   0
2013    0   1
```

To reverse the gender column, it will be:

```
pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['Gender'])[['m', 'f']]
```